# The use of modal logic in computer science

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I have a tentative understanding of modal logic.  Can anyone explain modal logic as it is used in computer science?

Comment: This is far too broad: a good answer would be at least a book chapter and possibly the whole book!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find many good examples if you search a bit online.  Some very-easy-to-find examples are in the following list:

From [Stanford Encyclopedia](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/)

> In computer science, labeled transition systems (LTSs) are commonly used to represent possible computation pathways during execution of a program.

Wikipedia has some examples in its article [modal logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic):

> Versions of temporal logic can be used in computer science to model computer operations and prove theorems about them. In one version, ◇P means "at a future time in the computation it is possible that the computer state will be such that P is true"; □P means "at all future times in the computation P will be true". In another version, ◇P means "at the immediate next state of the computation, P might be true"; □P means "at the immediate next state of the computation, P will be true".

Also, if you go to [Logic in Action](http://www.logicinaction.org/), you will find several examples, e.g.:

> [Chapter 6] introduces dynamic logic, a system that was introduced in computer science for reasoning about the behaviour of computer programs, by Vaughan Pratt and others, in the 1970s.
>
> In [Chapter 10] it is explained how predicate logic can be used for programming. The chapter gives an introduction to concepts used in automating logical theorem proving. This leads to computational tools underlying the well known logic programming language Prolog, popular in AI an in computational linguistics. The inferential mechanism behind Prolog is called SLD-resolution. This is the reasoning engine for a natural fragment of predicate logic (the so-called Horn-fragment).

Answer (score 0):

Modal logic is useful for verification of [reactive systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_system)

> A reactive system is a system that responds (reacts) to external events.
> Typically, biological systems are reactive, because they react to certain events. However, the term is used primarily for describing human-made systems. For example, a light consisting of a bulb and a switch is a reactive system, reacting to the user changing the switch position.

Specification of such systems may be given as a labelled transition system (LTS) or by some process algebra expressions (CCS for example).

In this context, both [safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_(distributed_computing)) and [livenss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liveness) properties are important:

> In distributed computing, **safety** properties informally require that "something bad will never happen"
>
> In distributed computing, **liveness** properties informally require that "something good eventually happens"

**Safety properties:**

- At most 1 process in critical section using a [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)
- No deadlocks

**Livness properties:**

- A request is eventually followed by a grant
- Every packet sent must be received at destination

Liveness properties should be specified and verified to ensure that the system makes progress and is "alive", while safety ensures that no bad state is reached.

Such properties can be specified using a (temporal) modal logic, such as [CTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_tree_logic)